# Is it possible to get an image of the process with highlighted active tasks in activiti-rest?

Tags: rest, activiti

I'm using activiti-rest. Is it possible to get an image of the process with highlighted active tasks?

Currently I get the BPM image using the following GET request:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following activiti REST url:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances/[processInstanceId]/diagram